# What is the probability that the first failure due to a solar-panel problem will occur after the 20th launch?

Tags: statistics

I have the answer to this but I could not figure out how to get to it. I used the Geometric Probability formula and added all of the probabilities up to 20 using $(1-p)^{(x-1)}p$ but I get a wrong answer. I would appreciate any explanation.

CosmoCo has started to manufacture, sell, and launch communications satellites. The most common reason for a satellite to fail once in orbit is a problem related to opening and initiating the solar panels. Suppose the probability of a failure related to the solar panels is 0.08. 
(Give your answer to four decimal places.)

CosmoCo is preparing an advertising campaign in which they claim to have had 20 successful launches in a row. What is the probability that the first failure due to a solar-panel problem will occur after the 20th launch?

Comment: What number do you get?

Comment: Hint: the probability that the first failure is after the $20$th launch is just the probability that the first $20$ launches were successful which is $(1-p)^{20}$. No muss, no fuss, no summing of geometric series etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$P(x \geq 21) = \displaystyle \sum_{k=21}^\infty (1-0.08)^{k-1}\cdot 0.08$.

Comment: I don't think that $P(X=21)$ is asked for, but rather $P(X \geq 21)$.